# onItemSelectedListener of a spinner in actionbar not called after switched between different tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner

I put a spinner as a custom view in a `spinner`. And it works well if I don't switch between different tabs in the `actionBar`. But when I do so a few times, the `onItemSelectedListener` seems not responding when I click an item in the spinner.
Why is it happening?

```
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.spinner_layout);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_spinner);
```

So, spinner is added into the `actionBar`. And the setting of spinner is as following:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.grade_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    //setSelection(int position) sometimes not work. boolean animation parameter is necessary
    spinner.setSelection(getSelection(), true);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("spinner", "on item selected");
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

Comment: @Lokesh code attached. Help plz

Comment: Have you implemented ActionBar.OnNavigationListener to your activity?? If you add spinner to actionbar, then you should implement it to your activity...

Comment: check this: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Comment: @Lokesh But I am using the `spinner` as a custom view in `actionBar`. And the navigation mode is `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`